# Tracking the finger touch using MotionEvent?

Tags: android, touch

what I am trying to do is:

- having multiple images in the screens, which will be acting as buttons.
- when a finger touch the screen and hover any image (any button), the image will be changed to another one(It will look like a hover button).
- when he hover another one, the same will happen and the previous one will return to its state.

I tried to track that using `OnTouchListener` and didn't work. Then, I read about [`Motionevent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and I think it might help but I didn't know for sure if it will.

Any one can answer or suggest a way to do this?

### ------------------------------------------------------

**UPDATE**

I tried this, but it seems not working. This is for `img1` The same code will be for `img2`:

```
    img1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true){
            if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img); //default image
            else
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pressed);

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To those who might be interested:

I couldn't find a solution to my problem under my target devices' level (API level 4). So, I gave up !

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a selector like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_hover" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**EDIT**

assign it to your ImageButton/Button drawable, then add logic in your code part to display the normal,selected and hover to get your desired look.

Comment: Can I assign a selector file to an `ImageView` ?

Comment: What do you mean by `logic` ?

Comment: The selector does NOT apply for `ImageView`